# how to know the details of app when a new app is created in podio?

Tags: api, webhooks, podio

I am calling a route on my server when a new app is create via webhooks. How to get the newly created app item details?
I am running apps integration server to get the details, calling a route on this server, is there any easy of getting newly created app item details?

Or is there any way like this

How do I get created item details in the webhook URL of Podio?
like in webhook https://api.domain.com/v1/message?appname={{app_name}}&itemname={{item_name}}&itemassignedto=
{{item_assigned_to}}

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is at: https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks

When the webhook is invoked you receive the parameter `app_id` in the POST request. That holds the app_id of the app that was created. USe that to get the full app using: https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-22349

Answer (score 0):

After you have saved the item with

```
$item->save();
```

simply add this to your API call and proceed as usual.

```
PodioItem:get($item->item_id);
```